# No ubuntu option in the boot menu

Tags: bootloader

My laptop is dual booted with windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04. But when I start my machine only windows option come for getting loaded. For loading ubuntu I have to go to bios then boot options and from there I have to select ubuntu. But ubuntu should also show up on the boot loader. When I installed ubuntu there were 2 options

1.To erase all data which would also remove the windows installation

2.To install ubuntu alongside windows. It was written there that I will get an option which os to choose each time the machine loads.

But that is not the case. What's wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu does not put Fedora into GRUB menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171947/ubuntu-does-not-put-fedora-into-grub-menu)

Answer (score 1):

It's a common issue while dual-booting Ubuntu and windows. Use `boot-repair` See [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and follow the instructions. Usually the default settings will work for most people. Good luck!

Comment: Not necessarily. Boot Repair will check if the the correct bootloader is installed and if not it will install it. The thing is, the OP's system is probably UEFI and the bootloader is likely to be there (at the UEFI partition) but not selected. So, it's probably a matter of setting the correct bootloader at UEFI, something Boot Repair won't and can't do.

Comment: So how do I do that